# Fail to authorize my request when using TickTick API

Tags: python, python-requests, openapi

I'm using the API described [here](https://developer.ticktick.com/docs/index.html#/openapi?id=getting-started) , using the default Python version in Google Collab notebook.

I have a client_id created as they recommend, but I can't figure out how to get the token back without having any redirect URL.

I aim to connect to my account in TickTick and do some bulk edits and deletes that the UI interface doesn't allow.

My code so far

```
import requests

payload = {'client_id': 'Ysf0D223UGhdlY5Y7W', 'scope': 'tasks:write','response_type':'code'}

r = requests.get('https://ticktick.com/oauth/authorize', params=payload)
r.text
```

Comment: "*I can't figure out how to get the token back without having any redirect URL.*" You could start a web server on an ephemeral port using something like Flask, load the `/oauth/authorize` URL in a web browser (and not via `requests` as you've currently configured), have the user complete the flow in said web browser to the point the service sends the requisite OAuth data back to that `localhost:XXXX` endpoint your script has set up. From there, you'd use Flask to extract the data from the resulting callback and use it to authorize future requests to the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try something like this. What I have done below is, first getting the auth code by using the same set of parameters that you have used, and then utilize the same auth code to grab the access token by using both client id and the secret:

```
import requests
    
auth_url = "https://ticktick.com/oauth/authorize"
params = {
    "response_type": "code",
    'scope': 'tasks:write',
    "client_id": 'Ysf0D223UGhdlY5Y7W'
}
response = requests.get(auth_url, params=params)
auth_code = response.url.split("=")[-1]
```

then use the auth code to get the token. Since I do not have the **client secret** i'm unable to test it.

```
token_url = "https://ticktick.com/oauth/token"
data = {
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": auth_code,
    "client_id": 'Ysf0D223UGhdlY5Y7W',
    "client_secret": client_secret
}
response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
token = response.json()["access_token"]
```